# Convert NSString to NSMutableArray to added in tableview

Tags: objective-c

Hi I wanted convert NSString into NSMutable array and in the final added into Tableview my String is this

```
result=Vlad,Mama,Papa,Son
```

I wanted to do something this

```
Anarray=(Vlad,Mama,Papa,Son)
```

And added to Tableview. Can anathing help me.What I do

```
    NSArray *arr = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
     dataArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:arr ,nil];
```

And try to added into

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [dataArray count];
}
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString*cellid=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell*cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if(cell==Nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
}
    cell.textLabel.text=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell; 
}
```

But I have mistake
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBqr2.png)

Comment: `dataArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:arr ,nil];` => `dataArray` will be a NSArray with only one object which is a array with 4 elements. You meant `dataArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:arr ,nil];`. And note that your question is about MutableArray, but you don't use mutables one, so what's the class of `dataArray` exactly? `NSMutableArray` of `NSArray`, if it's `NSMutableArray`, the previous line should throw a warning, and it should be `dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr ,nil];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've added your "arr" as element inside your "dataArray".

in case dataArray is NSMutableArray :

```
 dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

in case dataArray is NSArray :

```
 datatArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

Answer (score 1):

`componentsSeparatedByString` returns you the array, if you want a mutable array you can use the following code.

```
NSArray *arrComponents = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *arrmFilter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < [arrComponents count] ;i++)
{
    NSString *str = [arrComponents objectAtIndex:i];
    [arrmFilter addObject:str];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't alloc and init dataArray.

You can try below code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *arrData;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *str = @"objective c,swift,java";
    arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrData);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return  arrData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblData.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

componentsSeparatedByString gives you an array. Which is what you want.

[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:arr ,nil] gives you an array containing just one element, an array containing your strings. Which is totally wrong. An array containing four strings is absolutely not the same as an array containing an array containing four strings.

dataArray.count will be 1 - because there is *one* element which is itself an array. And dataArray [0] will be that array, not a string.